# Martingale method

Tags: python

I'm trying to simulate the [martingale method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_%28probability_theory%29), but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's my code:

```
import random

w = 1  # wager
# w1 = w  # an amount for reference when the wager has to go back to its original value
w = int(w)

br = 10000000  # Bankroll
# br1 = br  # Reference amount like w1
br = int(br)

losses = 0  # Keeps track of losses in loop
losses = int(losses)

wins = 0  # Keeps track of wins in loop
wins = int(wins)

b = 0  # Amount of bankruptcies that occur during the loop
b = int(b)

i = 1

boole = 0

x = 1
while x <= 1000:

    while i <= 100000:
        y = random.randint(0, 1)  # Picking between 1 or 0 for a %50 chance.
        if y == 1:  # If you win, you add the wager to the bankroll, add one to the wins, and set the wager to its beginning value
            br += w
            wins += 1
            w = 1

        else:
            br -= w  # If you lose, you subtract the wager from the bankroll, double the wager, and add a loss.
            w *= 2
            losses += 1

        if br <= 0:  # If the bankroll reaches 0 or below, it restarts adds to the bankruptcies variable
            b += 1
            break

        if boole == 1:
            w *= 2
            boole = 0

    i += 1  # Continues the loop
x += 1

print("Wins:", wins, "\nLosses:", losses, "\nBankruptcies:", b, "\nNet Gain:", )  # Stating info
```

For some reason it just doesn't work. I want it to output things, but it doesn't.

Edit: I'd appreciate it if you guys didn't stray too far from my original idea in to things I do not understand.

I basically want it to output how many times I won the 50/50 and how many times I lost. Also how many times I went bankrupt out of the 1000 in the x loop. As well as my net gain out of all the things.

Comment: Looks like using while you just exhoust your memory - you provide a large number of iterations so think about optimizing it

Comment: Unclear how going bankrupt should affect the computation of net gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it never ends is because your indentation is wrong for incrementing the counters. You also have a lot of unnecessary code. Here's a cleaned-up version, that will finish — so you can continue working on it.

```
import random

w = 1          # Wager
br = 10000000  # Bankroll
losses = 0     # Keeps track of losses in loop
wins = 0       # Keeps track of wins in loop
b = 0          # Amount of bankruptcies that occur during the loop
ng = 0         # Net gain
i = 1
x = 1
boole = 0

while x <= 1000:
    while i <= 100000:
        y = random.randint(0, 1)  # Picking between 1 or 0 for a %50 chance.
        if y == 1:   # If you win, you add the wager to the bankroll, add one to
                     # the wins, and set the wager to its beginning value
            br += w
            wins += 1
            w = 1
        else:
            br -= w   # If you lose, you subtract the wager from the bankroll,
                      # double the wager, and add a loss.
            w *= 2
            losses += 1

        if br <= 0:   # If the bankroll reaches 0 or below, it restarts adds to
                      # the bankruptcies variable
            b += 1
            break

        if boole == 1:  # Will never be True (nothing changes boole...)
            w *= 2
            boole = 0

        i += 1  # Increment the inner counter
    x += 1  # Increment the outer counter

print("Wins:", wins,
      "\nLosses:", losses,
      "\nBankruptcies:", b,
      "\nNet Gain:", ng)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! My only problem now is that b and ng always seem to be 0, and I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: The program is basically this: There's a coin flip, and if someone loses they double their wager. because of this, when they win they'll win back their money and their original wager. If they lose twice they quadruple their wager and the same thing happens. The program is supposed to simulate it. If you go bankrupt then the program adds to the bankrupt variable and breaks. Like I said though, nothing seems to happen to b or ng

Comment: Sorry, I didn't change the logic of what happens based on the result of each bet, so you'll need to debug that which you can do now that it's producing results. `ng` doesn't change because all I did is define it at the beginning so there would be something to print for "Net Gain" after the loop finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with iterator:

```
for x in  range(0,10):

   for i in range(0,100):

        y = random.randint(0, 1)  # Picking between 1 or 0 for a %50 chance.
        if y == 1:  #
            br += w
            wins += 1
            w = 1

        else:
            br -= w  # 
        w *= 2
        losses += 1

        if br <= 0:  # 

            b += 1
            break

        if boole == 1:
            w *= 2
            boole = 0


print("Wins:", wins, "\nLosses:", losses, "\nBankruptcies:", b, "\nNet Gain:", ) #
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tabbing over your incrementers i += 1 and x += 1.  They should line up with the other code in the loop and not with the while statements.